# Direct URL for executing a CloudFormation change set

Tags: aws-cloudformation

In AWS CloudFormation, I have some change sets:

```json
{
  "eks-alb-ingress-private-security-groups": [
    {
      "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:stack/eks-alb-ingress-private-security-groups/f452e940-3fe0-11ea-a91a-0a564743ac36",
      "StackName": "eks-alb-ingress-private-security-groups",
      "ChangeSetId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:changeSet/sceptre-change-set-eks-cluster-addons/2d497c25-2a02-4373-96c2-9f099076d264",
      "ChangeSetName": "sceptre-change-set-eks-cluster-addons",
      "ExecutionStatus": "AVAILABLE",
      "Status": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
      "CreationTime": "2020-03-17 08:05:53.943000+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

It is explained very well [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets-execute.html) how I can then go an execute that change set.

When applying many change sets, however, it would be convenient if I could somehow generate the direct URL to go to to execute the change, after I run `aws cloudformation list-change-sets`. That would save me a lot of clicking!

I tried beginning with:

```
https://ap-southeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=ap-southeast-2#/stacks/events?
```

And then URL encoding, using https://www.url-encode-decode.com:

```
encoded_stack_id=...
encoded_change_set_id=...
```

Leading to a generated URL:

```
url="https://ap-southeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=ap-southeast-2#/stacks/events?StackId=${encoded_stack_id}&ChangeSetId=${encoded_change_set_id}"
```

But that leads to this error being emitted:

```
You must specify a Stack ID. Displaying your Stacks page.

The URL specified is invalid.
You must specify both a Stack ID and a Change Set ID. Displaying your Stacks page.
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I finally got this to work:

Firstly, I installed `gridsite-clients`:

```
apt-get install gridsite-clients
```

Then:

```bash
main_part="https://ap-southeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=ap-southeast-2#/stacks/changesets/changes"

stack_id=$(urlencode \
  "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:stack/eks-alb-ingress-private-security-groups/f452e940-3fe0-11ea-a91a-0a564743ac36")

change_set_id=$(urlencode \
  "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:changeSet/sceptre-change-set-eks-cluster-addons/2d497c25-2a02-4373-96c2-9f099076d264")

url="$main_part?stackId=$stack_id&changeSetId=$change_set_id"
```

The variable `$url` then contains the Direct URL that takes you to the change-set-execute page in the AWS Console.